# Circle ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar

is there anyone that have idea to how create 3 circle `progressbar` inside each other ? I want something like image below. I tried some but when increase `thickness` of shape is becomes regtangle !!!
any suggestion ?

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="270"
android:toDegrees="270">
<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="11"
    android:useLevel="true">

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#007DD6"
        android:startColor="#007DD6"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

[image: like this]

but this is my result :

[image: result]

as you can see the thickness of `progressbar` is decreased.
and the other is how to set the gray `thickness` of `progressbar` same as the colored one !!

Comment: If you can create one circle then follow these steps

create once circle in `frame_layout` there after create another one with smaller radios. or else tell me if you can't create circle using java

Comment: question updated @AMANSINGH

Comment: don't use this drawable code for creating circle. use java code for creating circle that will help you

Comment: can you post a sample code ! I have no idea about using java to create circle @AMANSINGH

Answer (score 0):

Draw a circle like this using java. Create java class `CircleImageView` and write this piece of code

```
public class CircleImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
private static final int DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR = Color.TRANSPARENT;
private static final boolean DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY = false;

private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();
private final Paint mFillPaint = new Paint();

private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
private int mFillColor = DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR;

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
private int mBitmapWidth;
private int mBitmapHeight;

private float mDrawableRadius;
private float mBorderRadius;

private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

private boolean mReady;
private boolean mSetupPending;
private boolean mBorderOverlay;

public CircleImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

    mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
    mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    mBorderOverlay = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_overlay, DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY);
    mFillColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_fill_color, DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR);

    a.recycle();

    init();
}

private void init() {
    super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
    mReady = true;

    if (mSetupPending) {
        setup();
        mSetupPending = false;
    }
}

@Override
public ScaleType getScaleType() {
    return SCALE_TYPE;
}

@Override
public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
    if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
    }
}

@Override
public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
    if (adjustViewBounds) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("adjustViewBounds not supported.");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mBitmap == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mFillColor != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mDrawableRadius, mFillPaint);
    }
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
    if (mBorderWidth != 0) {
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    setup();
}

public int getBorderColor() {
    return mBorderColor;
}

public void setBorderColor(@ColorInt int borderColor) {
    if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderColor = borderColor;
    mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
    invalidate();
}

public void setBorderColorResource(@ColorRes int borderColorRes) {
    setBorderColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(borderColorRes));
}

public int getFillColor() {
    return mFillColor;
}

public void setFillColor(@ColorInt int fillColor) {
    if (fillColor == mFillColor) {
        return;
    }

    mFillColor = fillColor;
    mFillPaint.setColor(fillColor);
    invalidate();
}

public void setFillColorResource(@ColorRes int fillColorRes) {
    setFillColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(fillColorRes));
}

public int getBorderWidth() {
    return mBorderWidth;
}

public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
    if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
    setup();
}

public boolean isBorderOverlay() {
    return mBorderOverlay;
}

public void setBorderOverlay(boolean borderOverlay) {
    if (borderOverlay == mBorderOverlay) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderOverlay = borderOverlay;
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    mBitmap = bm;
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
    super.setImageResource(resId);
    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
    super.setImageURI(uri);
    mBitmap = uri != null ? getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable()) : null;
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    if (cf == mColorFilter) {
        return;
    }

    mColorFilter = cf;
    mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
    invalidate();
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private void setup() {
    if (!mReady) {
        mSetupPending = true;
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 && getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (mBitmap == null) {
        invalidate();
        return;
    }

    mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

    mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
    mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

    mFillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mFillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mFillPaint.setColor(mFillColor);

    mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

    mBorderRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f);

    mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect);
    if (!mBorderOverlay) {
        mDrawableRect.inset(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth);
    }
    mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2.0f, mDrawableRect.width() / 2.0f);

    updateShaderMatrix();
    invalidate();
}

private void updateShaderMatrix() {
    float scale;
    float dx = 0;
    float dy = 0;

    mShaderMatrix.set(null);

    if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
        scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
        dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
    } else {
        scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
        dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
    }

    mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.left, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.top);

    mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
}

}
```

and use this in your xml like

```
 <com.yourpackagename.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileImg"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />
```

Or else go through this link this is what you are looking for [circular progress bar](https://github.com/GIGAMOLE/ArcProgressStackView%20%22%22)

Comment: how to set the progress percent ?

Comment: check my edited answer and use. This will show animated progress bar what you are looking for. upvote and accept answer once you got

Comment: did you got your ans @Hamed